# Collision detection

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to create a collision detection method that checks if two of my objects (2 oval shaped uiimages) collide with each other. if they do it should set the BOOL value to YES otherwise it should set it to NO.

So far it just goes to the IF-statement that checks if Ruby1 is above Ruby2. It doesn't care if ruby1 is below ruby2 or even to the left or to the right of it. it just keeps going to that IF statement. and vice versa.

```
-(void)CollisionDetect{


//can't be colliding because Ruby1 is too far left of Ruby2

if( rubin1.frame.origin.x + rubin1.bounds.size.width < rubin2.frame.origin.x){

    CollisionRubies = NO;
    NSLog(@"Collision left");
}

//can't be colliding because Ruby1 is too far right of Ruby2

if( rubin1.frame.origin.x > rubin2.frame.origin.x + rubin2.bounds.size.width){

    CollisionRubies = NO;
    NSLog(@"Collision right");
}

//can't be colliding because Ruby1 is too far below Ruby2

if( rubin1.frame.origin.y + rubin1.bounds.size.width < rubin2.frame.origin.y){
    CollisionRubies = NO;
    NSLog(@"Collision below");
}

//can't be colliding because Ruby1 is too far above Ruby2

if( rubin1.frame.origin.y < rubin2.frame.origin.y + rubin2.bounds.size.width){
    CollisionRubies = NO;
    NSLog(@"Collision above");
}

    if( rubin2.frame.origin.x + rubin2.bounds.size.width < rubin1.frame.origin.x){

    CollisionRubies = NO;
    NSLog(@"Collision left");
}

//can't be colliding because Ruby2 is too far right of Ruby1

if( rubin2.frame.origin.x > rubin1.frame.origin.x + rubin1.bounds.size.width){

    CollisionRubies = NO;
    NSLog(@"Collision right");
}

//can't be colliding because Ruby2 is too far below Ruby1

if( rubin2.frame.origin.y + rubin2.bounds.size.width < rubin1.frame.origin.y){
    CollisionRubies = NO;
    NSLog(@"Collision below");
}

//can't be colliding because Ruby2 is too far above Ruby1

if( rubin2.frame.origin.y < rubin1.frame.origin.y + rubin1.bounds.size.width){
    CollisionRubies = NO;
    NSLog(@"Collision above");
}

//if we get here, the two rects MUST be colliding
CollisionRubies = YES;
NSLog(@"Collision detected");
```

}

if the BOOL value is NO then ruby1 will move to that position as shown in the code below otherwise it will stop moving until it detects that ruby2 isn't in front of it. and vice versa.

```
-(void)dispatchTouchEvent:(UIView *)theView toPosition:(CGPoint)position{
// Check to see which view, or views,  the point is in and then move to that position.
if (CGRectContainsPoint([rubin1 frame], position)) {

    if(!CollisionRubies){

        rubin1.center = position;
    }
     if (CGRectContainsPoint([rubin2 frame], position)) {

    if(!CollisionRubies){

        rubin2.center = position;
    }


}
```

the collision detection method is called from the touchesmoved method

```
 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

[self CollisionDetect];

 NSLog(@"touchesMoved");
 if(!GamePaused){
         // Enumerates through all touch objects
         for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

             // Send to the dispatch method, which will make sure the appropriate subview is acted upon
             [self dispatchTouchEvent:[touch view] toPosition:[touch locationInView:self.view]];
         }
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

*****************UPDATE********************************************************

```
-(void)CollisionDetect{
```

//can't be colliding because Ruby1 is too far left of Ruby2

if( rubin1.frame.origin.x + rubin1.bounds.size.width < rubin2.frame.origin.x){

```
CollisionRubies = NO;
NSLog(@"Collision left");
```

}

//can't be colliding because Ruby1 is too far right of Ruby2

else if( rubin1.frame.origin.x > rubin2.frame.origin.x + rubin2.bounds.size.width){

```
CollisionRubies = NO;
NSLog(@"Collision right");
```

}

//can't be colliding because Ruby1 is too far below Ruby2

else if( rubin1.frame.origin.y + rubin1.bounds.size.width < rubin2.frame.origin.y){
    CollisionRubies = NO;
    NSLog(@"Collision below");
}

//can't be colliding because Ruby1 is too far above Ruby2

else if( rubin1.frame.origin.y < rubin2.frame.origin.y + rubin2.bounds.size.width){
    CollisionRubies = NO;
    NSLog(@"Collision above");
}

```
if( rubin2.frame.origin.x + rubin2.bounds.size.width < rubin1.frame.origin.x){

CollisionRubies = NO;
NSLog(@"Collision left");
```

}

//can't be colliding because Ruby2 is too far right of Ruby1

else if( rubin2.frame.origin.x > rubin1.frame.origin.x + rubin1.bounds.size.width){

```
CollisionRubies = NO;
NSLog(@"Collision right");
```

}

//can't be colliding because Ruby2 is too far below Ruby1

else if( rubin2.frame.origin.y + rubin2.bounds.size.width < rubin1.frame.origin.y){
    CollisionRubies = NO;
    NSLog(@"Collision below");
}

//can't be colliding because Ruby2 is too far above Ruby1

else if( rubin2.frame.origin.y < rubin1.frame.origin.y + rubin1.bounds.size.width){
    CollisionRubies = NO;
    NSLog(@"Collision above");
}

else{
//if we get here, the two rects MUST be colliding
CollisionRubies = YES;
NSLog(@"Collision detected");
}

Comment: Shouldn't you use size.height on the vertical (y)?

Comment: the code is based on the 2d collision detection code mentioned in the book iPhone Game Development and there it said .width but i agree it feels like it should be .height instead. tried it though and it didn't work. is there maybe another way to create th ecollision methos and get the same results that I'm looking for?

Comment: I'd suggest that perhaps the book has a misprint.  When working through things from books, it's better to use it as a guide rather than just copying the code - work it out with a pencil and paper if necessary and this will not only help you remove bugs, but will aid your understanding of the subject matter.

Comment: that's what I did actually... I modified it, not just copied it ;)

Comment: My misunderstanding.  I took it that you meant you had just copied it!

Answer (score 1):

Just as a side note, if you used an else if your code might be a bit more efficient, especially if you are calling on the CollisionDetect often, which I assume you are. This way if one of the earlier if statements strikes true, you can ignore the remaining.

Comment: I tried it out with else if etc... I´ve updated the code above with the new method... it didn't go inside the code tags unfortunately. any way... this time it seemed accordingly to the NSLog´s that it entered all IF statements... depending on the location... the only thing remaining now is how to stop them from passing through each other... CollisionRubies never became YES :(

Answer (score 0):

In your `CollisionDetect` method, you are setting `CollisionRubies = NO` at various points, but you are then setting `CollisionRubies = YES` at the end regardless of any tests that have just happened.  You might have well just had the method be one line

```
-(void)CollisionDetect{
  CollisionRubies = YES;
}
```

Also, there seems to be a problem with your calculations of the collisions (width being mixed with y when calculating above or below)

I would also suggest you read the objective-C coding style guide.  For example, use lowercase first letter for variables and method names.  For example, `collisionRubies` and `-(void)collisionDetect` This helps other people read your code quicker if it is written in a standard way.

Comment: the images are oval shaped. so I thought that doing it this way would be "easier" to determine if the images are intersecting with each other. What I mean is that the only thing that I'm trying to do is to make these two movable images to not be able to go through each other. any suggestions of how to do that?

Comment: You're on the right lines, but you just need to work out your calculations (not mixing the width with the y value).  Draw many scenarios on paper and check your calculations.  But you do need to fix your logic in the CollisionDetect method as you are just settings CollisionRubies to YES all the time regardless of what else happens.

Comment: I'll try...  but I don't know how to continue from here actually...
I'm just trying to make them not being able to pass through each other when I move them around on the screen (with my finger)... maybe there is another way of doing this... any suggestions?

Comment: If you are new to programming, you might want to get a better understanding of the basics before trying to launch into something like this. If you are trying to write a game, I would suggest looking at something like Cocos2D.

Comment: I thought of making the game in Cocos2d but then I thought that it would be better for me to learn this way first.. the basics first... :)

my next project will probably be in Cocos2D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of four functions that check collision from the four directions why don't you use

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(ruby1.frame,ruby2.frame)
{
//your code
}
```

This, ofcourse, only when you don't need to know the direction from which one object approached the other.

Comment: I cannot use that since the images are oval shaped :(... i tried that way as well

Comment: the starting points are to close so the BOOL value of CollisionRubies turns to YES right away when the game starts... 
the starting position of the images should be close from the beginning by the way... but not on top of each other

Comment: The CollisionRubies turns to YES right away becuase of your logic in the CollisionDetect method.  See my answer for details.